# Android. LibGDX. How to move and orient 3D-object along a spline

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, libgdx, spline

I'm using LibGDX for my Android app. I need to move and orient 3D object(ModelInstance) along a spline.In my case it's CatmullRomSpline. I got the movement working but having problem with orienting the ModelInstance along the spline.

My Code:

```
public void update() {
    float t = SPEED * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    elapsedTime = elapsedTime + SPEED *  Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();       

    //Movement
    catmull.valueAt(value, elapsedTime);
    myObject3d.transform.setTranslation(value);

    //Rotation
    derivative = catmull.derivativeAt(derivative, t);
    derivative = derivative.nor();

    //Tried to bring object into default position before rotating
    //Vector.X - is the default direction of my Object - facing right
    //myObject3d.transform.rotate(Vector3.X, Vector3.X);

    myObject3d.transform.rotate(derivative, Vector3.X);             
}
```

Comment: Try `myObject3d.transform.setToRotation(derivative, Vector3.X).trn(value);`. Note that there are infinite possibilities of a rotation resulting in that direction though. Depending on the spline you might need an `up` and/or `right` vector as well.

Comment: Thanks! Will try and let you know the results.

Comment: Hi. I tried it. It is much better than before. Object rotates as is goes along the spline. But the actual orientation is wrong. My object is initially facing along the X axis. So I'd expect setToRotation(derivative, Vector3.X) will make my object's face to look in the direction of the derivative. Or am I wrong here somewhere? Also I remember there was LibGDX demo/exmaple where a 3D-arrow was navigating the spline. And it was easily done. Like some function to follow the path. Can't find it now though:( Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Matrix4#rotate](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Matrix4.html#rotate-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-) method has two arguments, `base` and `target`. In your case the base vector should be `Vector3.X`, while the target is `derivative`. You need to swap the arguments for this. Also, the [Matrix4#rotate](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Matrix4.html#rotate-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-) method post-multiplies the rotation on top the existing rotation. Or in other words: this will accumulate the absolute rotation on every call. You probably want to use the [Matrix4#setToRotation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Matrix4.html#setToRotation-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-) method instead, which resets the rotation on every call (clears the matrix).

```
myObject3d.transform.setToRotation(Vector3.X, derivative);
myObject3d.transform.setTranslation(value);
```

While this probably will work in most cases, you might get unexpected results depending on the path. Like said, there are infinite possible rotations that will result in this direction. Therefor it's better to use two additional vectors to specify the up (Y) and right (Z) vector.

```
right.set(Vector3.Y).crs(derivative).nor();
up.set(right).crs(derivative).nor();
myObject3d.transform.set(derivative, up, right, position).rotate(Vector3.X, 180);
```

Here the cross product is used to calculate the right and up vectors, where it is assumed that `Vector3.Y` is usually close to the up vector. Then the [Matrix4#set](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Matrix4.html#set-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-) method is used to set the matrix to reflect these values. The first argument specifies the "new" X-axis, the second the "new" Y-axis, the third the "new" Z-axis and the last argument specifies the translation (location).

Here's a working example: https://gist.github.com/xoppa/7558c0c75e9534795e9f

Although unrelated, keep in mind that [path.valueAt](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Path.html#valueAt-T-float-) method uses `0 <= t <= 1`. Or in other words, `t` (`elapsedTime` in your code) should not be below 0 or above 1.

Comment: The first option worked well except when I did a spline u-turn(So my object could u-turn) my object started doing weird rotations even though the spline was a straight line after u-turn. Tried the code from your example - works completely diffrerent at all stages. My object gets skewed somehow and is turned in the wrong direction. (But the strange rotations are gone). I would add images. but don't know where to put them? Maybe update the question?

Comment: I created another questions for this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450272/android-lidgdx-following-catmullrom-spline-produces-weird-results-in-3d

Comment: If it is skewed then you probably need to normalize the vector after the cross product as well. To fix the rotation (e.g. if it is upside down) you can add an additional rotation. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. That helped! Thanks again for help. Saved lots of time for me!