# Android. LidGDX. Following CatmullRom spline produces weird results in 3D

Tags: android, vector, 3d, libgdx, spline

I have a 3D-object that is navigating the CatmullRom spline. The code I'm using is taken from Xoppa's answer here: [Xoppa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369012/android-libgdx-how-to-move-and-orient-3d-object-along-a-spline/28411771#28411771)

There are 2 ways of aligning object along thre spline. I tried both of them. And have weird results with both.
Option 1 (it mostly OK but have a weird rotations occuring...see image below):
[image]

Option 2 (removes issue from Option 1 but everything else is not okay..see image below ): 
[image]

My spline:

```
    pointsArray = new Vector3[21];
    pointsArray[0] = new Vector3(-5, -2, 2);
    pointsArray[1] = new Vector3(-4F, -1F, 2);
    pointsArray[2] = new Vector3(-3F, -0.5F, 2);
    pointsArray[3] = new Vector3(-2.0F, 0.3F, 2);
    pointsArray[4] = new Vector3(-1.0F, 0F, 2);
    pointsArray[5] = new Vector3(0F, -0.5F, 2);
    pointsArray[6] = new Vector3(1F, 0.5F, 2);
    pointsArray[7] = new Vector3(3F, 1F, 2);

    //loop
    pointsArray[8] = new Vector3(3.5F, 1F, 2.25F);
    pointsArray[9] = new Vector3(3.6F, 1F, 2.5F);
    pointsArray[10] = new Vector3(3.5F, 1F, 2.75F);
    pointsArray[11] = new Vector3(3F, 1F, 3F);
    pointsArray[12] = new Vector3(2.5F, 1F, 2.75F);
    pointsArray[13] = new Vector3(2F, 1F, 2.5F);
    pointsArray[14] = new Vector3(1.5F, 1F, 2.25F);
    pointsArray[15] = new Vector3(1F, 1F, 2.2F);
    pointsArray[16] = new Vector3(0F, 1.2F, 2F);


    pointsArray[17] = new Vector3(-1F, 1F, 2F);
    pointsArray[18] = new Vector3(-2F, 1.2F, 2F);
    pointsArray[19] = new Vector3(-3F, 1F, 2F);
    pointsArray[20] = new Vector3(-4F, 0.8F, 2F);

    catmull = new CatmullRomSpline<Vector3>(pointsArray, false);
```

So I need either to eliminate the rotations from option1. Or (think much simpler) to fix the option2 to rotate my object correctly. I think there's a simple thing that I'm missing that someone who's good with vectors can spot easily.